# How to call Finder Method with Parameters using BCS Runtime Model

Tags: 2010, bcs

Hi I have created BCS model which use secure store service for authentication to External system.Everything works fine using out of box external list and BCS web parts.

But I want to create custom web part, so I need to call finder method in web part programmatically. In BCS I have finder method with three parameters username,password and current User.

How can I call finder method programmatically with these 3 parameters?

Please advise.

Thanks

Ronak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Connect to the BDC Service Application proxy
BdcService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>();
if (service == null)
    throw new Exception("No BDC Service Application found.");

//Connect to metadata catalog
DatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog catalog = service.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));

//Get entity
IEntity ect = catalog.GetEntity(entityNamespace, entityName);

//Get LobSystem
ILobSystem lob = ect.GetLobSystem();

//Get LobSystemInstance
ILobSystemInstance lobi = lob.GetLobSystemInstances()[lobSystemInstance];

//Get Method Instance
IMethodInstance mi = ect.GetMethodInstance(specificFinderMethodInstance, MethodInstanceType.SpecificFinder);

//Get Parameters
IParameterCollection parameters = mi.GetMethod().GetParameters();

//Set Parameters
object[] arguments = new object[parameters.Count];
arguments[0] = entityInstanceIdentifier;

//Execute
ect.Execute(mi, lobi, ref arguments);

//Display
PropertyInfo[] props = arguments[1].GetType().GetProperties();
PropertyInfo prop = props[0];
SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)(prop.GetValue(arguments[1], null));
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(3) + " " + reader.GetString(5));
    }
}
```

Source: [TechNet: Call custom BCS methods from a webpart](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sharepoint2010programming/thread/72ee9d06-227e-410d-8dd6-05406d6b610b)

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your reply and code.i do have this code from Scott book and i have used this code to call Finder Method in webparts and it worked.Now i have IEnumerable Items of some entity lets say Workspace now i want to get datatable or collection of objects how can i do that.